# Output doesn't as expected in java code problem

Tags: java, loops, methods, output, new-operator

I am new in java. I am working on a problem to fill the corral with snails which is out to pasture based on random swing direction. But output is not as expected.

```
package fill;

import java.util.Random;

public class FillTheCorral extends Gate {

    public static final int sRANDOM_SEED=1234;

    private static final int sMAX_GATES=4;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Random randomNumber=new Random(sRANDOM_SEED);
        FillTheCorral mFillTheCorral=new FillTheCorral();
        Gate[] corral=new Gate[sMAX_GATES];
        for (int i=0; i<corral.length; i++) {
            corral[i]=new Gate();
        }
        do {
            mFillTheCorral.setCorralGates(corral , randomNumber);
        } while (!mFillTheCorral.anyCorralAvailable(corral));
    }
    
    public void setCorralGates(Gate[] gate, Random selectDirection) {
        System.out.println("Initial gate setup:");
        for(int i=0;i<gate.length;i++){
            int randDir = selectDirection.nextInt(3)-1; 
            gate[i].setSwing(randDir);
            System.out.println("Gate " + i + ": "+ randDir);
        }
    }

    public boolean anyCorralAvailable(Gate[] corral) {
        for(int i=0;i<corral.length;i++){
            if(corral[i].getSwingDirection() == IN)
                return true;
        }
        return false ;
    }
}

class Gate {
    public static final int OUT=-1;
    public static final int IN=1;
    public static final int CLOSED=0;
    private static int mSwing;

    public static
    int getSwingDirection () {
        return mSwing;
    }

    public static boolean setSwing (int dir) {
        mSwing=dir;
        if (mSwing == IN) return true;
        if (mSwing == OUT) return true;
        if (mSwing == CLOSED) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int thru (int count) {
        if (getSwingDirection() == IN) {
            return +count;
        } else if (getSwingDirection() == OUT) {
            return -count;
        } else {
              count*=0;
              return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output :
Initial gate setup:
Gate 0: 1
Gate 1: 1
Gate 2: 1
Gate 3: -1

Actual output:

Initial gate setup:
Gate 0: 1
Gate 1: 1
Gate 2: 1
Gate 3: -1

Initial gate setup:
Gate 0: 1
Gate 1: -1
Gate 2: 0
Gate 3: 0

Initial gate setup:
Gate 0: -1
Gate 1: 0
Gate 2: 0
Gate 3: 1

I am getting x3 times gate random direction.

Comment: Check the size of your `gate` argument you receive in the `setCorralGates` method. Just print it for the debugging purposes. Is it really 4? no? why?

Comment: I have created Gate[] gate object with sMAX_GATES which is 4 in size.

Comment: ..and how many times is `mFillTheCorral.setCorralGates` called in your do-while? why don't you use debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in your `Gate` class you defined the field `mSwing` ands its getters/setters as `static`. A static field only exists once per class, meaning all your 4 created Gate objects will share the same value for `mSwing` instead of every gate having its own value for `mSwing`.

For mor information please read: [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

If you change the field to a normal non-static one you will get the output you expect:

```
private int mSwing;

public int getSwingDirection () {
    return mSwing;
}

public boolean setSwing (int dir) {
    mSwing=dir;
    if (mSwing == IN) return true;
    if (mSwing == OUT) return true;
    if (mSwing == CLOSED) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `mSwing` of Gate is static. When you call `gate[i].setSwing(randDir)` in the for loop, you are replacing the same static variable every time. That's why your while loop ends only when Gate 3 == 1.

Try to remove static from `mSwing` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are declaring the variable *mSwing* as **static**, which means it's not related to each individual object but with the class, all objects will share the same value.

So, when you call *getSwingDirection()* from the object, it will return the class static variable which contains the last value set by the method *setSwing()*.

I added a log to show you the results at

```
public boolean anyCorralAvailable(Gate[] corral) {
    System.out.println("Value of getSwingDirection():");
    for (int i = 0; i < corral.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("corral[" +i + "]: " + corral[i].getSwingDirection());
        if (corral[i].getSwingDirection() == IN)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Result with the **static** mofifier:

```
Initial gate setup:
Gate 0: 1
Gate 1: 1
Gate 2: 1
Gate 3: -1
Value of getSwingDirection():
corral[0]: -1
corral[1]: -1
corral[2]: -1
corral[3]: -1
Initial gate setup:
Gate 0: 1
Gate 1: -1
Gate 2: 0
Gate 3: 0
Value of getSwingDirection():
corral[0]: 0
corral[1]: 0
corral[2]: 0
corral[3]: 0
Initial gate setup:
Gate 0: -1
Gate 1: 0
Gate 2: 0
Gate 3: 1
Value of getSwingDirection():
corral[0]: 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Result without the **static** mofifier:

```
Initial gate setup:
Gate 0: 1
Gate 1: 1
Gate 2: 1
Gate 3: -1
Value of getSwingDirection():
corral[0]: 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Removing the **static** modifier from *mSwing* and consequently from methods *setSwing()* and *getSwingDirection()* would fix your problem.